# Docker port bind fails. Why a "permission denied"?

Tags: windows, docker, jenkins

I'm trying to start a `jenkinsci/blueocean` container under Windows 10 Pro (latest). I'm running a script:

```
docker run ^
  --rm ^
  -u root ^
  -d ^
  -p 8080:8080 ^
  -p 50000:50000 ^
  -v D:/docker/jenkins/volumes/jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home ^
  -v D:/docker/jenkins/volumes/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ^
  -v D:/docker/jenkins/volumes/home:/home ^
  jenkinsci/blueocean
```

This fails with the following message:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: 
  driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint elastic_kare: 
  Error starting userland proxy: 
    Bind for 0.0.0.0:50000: unexpected error Permission denied
```

If I leave out the binding of port 50000 it works fine, but I need the 50000 port to communicate with the slaves on the host.

Binding 50000 to another port doesn't help. The port is not in use, according to `netstat -an`. Trying to run the script as Administrator didn't help.

What could be the issue here?

update: I restarted my laptop and updated Docker Desktop to the latest version as well.

update2: after restarting laptop I restarten Docker (several times) as well. To no avail.

update3: shutting down the Windows Firewall did not solve the problem.

Comment: After restarting your laptop, you might require restart docker as well.. Which is a dirty work around imho. Also, try running it as admin maybe? I say it is a long shot though. Lastly can you use other ports (e.g. 48000) rather than 50000? Try the other combinations. 50000:48000 or 48000:50000 or 48000:48000

Comment: Tried it (several times), didn't work.

Comment: is it a machine with a firewall? so is something blocking that port?

Comment: Checked the firewall as well, no result.

Answer (score 21):

If you're running Docker on Windows then it will be using Hyper-V - I've found that Hyper-V reserves a bunch of ports - you can find out by running this:

```
netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp
```

On my machine I could see it had reserved port 50000. To free this port up I disabled Hyper-V:

```
dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

After the reboots, I reserved port 50000:

```
netsh int ipv4 add excludedportrange protocol=tcp startport=50000 numberofports=1
```

Then enabled Hyper-V again:

```
dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All
```

When it came back up I could run Jenkins in Docker on Windows:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

Comment: nice explanation especially for hyper-v related port reserved. thanks.

Comment: Wow! Finally, I understand this freaking permission denied errors!

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue and after changing the port for docker it get resolved. I was using port 50062 that was reserved by Hyper-V. I confirm this by issuing the below command.

`netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp`

```
Start Port    End Port

 36259       36259
 49675       49774
 49875       49974
 50000       50059
 50060       50159
 50160       50259
 50260       50359
 50360       50459
 50614       50713

* - Administered port exclusions.
```

after changing the port I was able to start the container.